# BroadcastReceiver & getIntent() difference

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcast

Thtat was a dumb question. Got the answers after searching ;)

Comment: Did you at least read the documentation for the `BroadcastReceiver` and also what `getIntent()` does?

Comment: A differentiation between the two is required when you are confused between the uses of the two. What do you know about their uses? Write down the points that confuse you.

Comment: @luks yep i read them.. thats what made me confused!
sanjeev see below..

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear, it's like asking us to explain you the difference between a dog and a car. Please read the BroadcastReceiver documentation carefully, find some tutorials on their use to understand what they're designed for.

Comment: @NamanArora : i think `BroadcastReceiver` is `Apple` and `getIntent()` is `pizza`

Comment: I think he wants to know why Activities use getIntent, and broadcastreceivers have a parameter in onReceive. BroadcastReceivers don't have a getIntent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getIntent()` is used to get the `Intent` that started the `Activity`. For an `Activity` it is not always needed to know which `Intent` started him. Because for example a `startActivity` from the `Launcher` is nothing special.
Only case an `Activity` wants to explicitly know it when he wants to do something special. Such as 'create email' instead of going to the mail application.

Remember only 1 `Intent` can start 1 `Activity`.

A `BroadcastReceiver` is a component that registers himself on one or more `Intents`. If that `Intent` is send/broadcasted via `sendBroadcast`, this `BroadcastReceiver` will be started. As such a `BroadcastReceiver` allways wants to know which `Intent` has started him, `WIFI_CONNECTED`, or similar. To my understanding thats why there is a parameter on the `onReceive`, compared to a `Activity` which only has a `getIntent()`. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Remember only 1 `Intent` is send, and 0 or more `BroadcastReceivers` can be started. (All those who are registered are launched)

Comment: Awesome! Really simple and to the point! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Android uses the concept of a receiver and the concept of `"Broadcasting”` intents to help you essentially listen for certain actions that occur on the phone. You can implement a receiver to listen to your own intents which you might send around internally within your application (i.e. perhaps a change was made to one of your application’s data sets and you want to broadcast this to your receiver and have the receiver do some additional work), but again, receivers are most often used to listen to intents which are broadcasted by the system itself!

For Example:

In your Android manifest define a new receiver to be:

> ```
> <receiver android:name=".receivers.PhoneIntentReceiver" android:enabled="true">
> <intent-filter>
>     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
> </intent-filter>
> </receiver>
> ```

Basically, you are defining a receiver object called `PhoneIntentReceiver` in your `manifest` which is enabled and which will listen for system broadcasts with the action type `PHONE_STATE`. This particular `intent` gets broadcasted by the system whenever there is an incoming call or whenever you hangup an existing phone call (i.e. when the state of your phone changes).

And the actual class which will look something like this:

> ```
>   public class PhoneIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   
>     @Override   
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
>   //get the data from the passed intent   
>   //this is the intent that was broadcasted by the system   
>   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();    
>   String phoneState = bundle.getString("state");
>   String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
>   //perform operations using phoneState data
> }
> ```
>
> }

So notice we extend the `BroadcastReceiver` class and override the `onReceive` method. This gets called whenever the intent with action `PHONE_STATE` is broadcasted, and from there we can get the extra information that was stored in the `intent` and play around with it. Notice that in this case, the action extra is the “state”, and here the state will be either “RINGING”, “OFFHOOK”, or “IDLE”.

I hope you will get the difference now.